# Как в JS менять свойства объектов при переборе их массива?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Первый день на JS, если что. Итак, есть, например, такой код:

```
function Object1(a, b) {
  this.a = 0;
  this.b = 0;

  this.sum = function() {
    alert(a + b);
  }
};

objs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  objs.push(new Object1(1, 1));
}


setInterval(function() {
  for (var i in objs) {
    objs[i].b++;
    objs[i].sum();
  }
}, 200);
```

В алерте всегда выводится 2, т. е. фактически значение b не меняется. Как его можно изменить в этих условиях?

Comment: `alert(this.a + this.b);`  ибо a и b  ни на что не указывают в функции(методе)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, именно это... Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Этого хотели? Используйте только лучше console.log()... приятнее-удобнее ;)

```
function Object1(a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;

  this.sum = function() {
    console.log(this.a + this.b);
  }
};

objs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  objs.push(new Object1(1, 1));
}

setInterval(function() {
  for (var i in objs) {
    objs[i].b++;
    objs[i].sum();
  }
}, 200);
```